# Autoscrolling in a UIScrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autoscroll

I have been only using Xcode 5 for a little while now and I need help when it comes to auto scrolling a `UIScrollView`. I am using a single view application. I need the screen to scroll down at a pace that speeds up incrementally. Also I need the screen to keep progressing even when the screen is touched. If someone can explain which code goes where it would be great! Your help will be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: [`setContentOffset:animated:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollview_class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/setContentOffset:animated:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, just adding this from your [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500234/autoscrolling-the-uiscrollview).

I suspect the *Piano Tiles* game is actually using something like `Sprite Kit`.

This allows a lot more control over thing like "scrolling" speed.

Instead of using a `UIScrollView` you would use an `SKNode` as a layer with the buttons added to that parent layer.

Then using the `update` game loop you can incrementally increase the speed of the movement based on the time since the game started.

In essence... don't use `UIScrollView`, don't use `UIKit`, use `SpriteKit`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this library: https://github.com/danielamitay/DAAutoScroll

It stops to scroll when the user touches the screen and that's the only solution I see possible. I don't even see why you wouldn't want the user to be able to stop the scrolling..

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few options:

1) suggested by Fogmeister, use Sprite Kit instead.

2) see [setContentOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977640/uiscrollview-and-setcontentoffset)

3) just use a normal view as parent, then have another child view on top with the full content (would be longer than the parent view), create a NSTimer to periodically call a method which scrolls the child view in whatever direction and speed as required.
Note that might need something on top to mask around the child view from showing the suppose-to-be-hidden sections of the child view.

Hope this helps