# Autoscrolling the UIscrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autoscroll

I have already asked the same question a few time but I have had no answer.

I would like to know if someone can help me get a `UIScrollview` to **autoscroll down** the page with an **incrementally faster speeds**.

I also have buttons on the page. 
It would also be great when the user touches a button on the page it keeps autoscrolling.
So if you kind of understand it will be like the game *Piano Tiles*.

I am running Xcode 5. If someone has the solution to my problem please can you tell me what code goes where as I am quite a newby Xcode.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.:)

Comment: Also, you asked this identical question 9 hours ago. Creating a duplicate is not the way to do this. Ever. You can edit your original question to add more information and it will bump the question. Never create duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the *Piano Tiles* game is actually using something like `Sprite Kit`.

This allows a lot more control over thing like "scrolling" speed.

Instead of using a `UIScrollView` you would use an `SKNode` as a layer with the buttons added to that parent layer.

Then using the `update` game loop you can incrementally increase the speed of the movement based on the time since the game started.

In essence... don't use `UIScrollView`, don't use `UIKit`, use `SpriteKit`.

Comment: @AdamMahmoud no worries, happy to help. Don't duplicate next time though :)